# How do I get Fangora to drop more beads in Kirby's Epic Yarn?

Tags: kirbys-epic-yarn

I am trying to unlock the bonus levels in Grass Land.

Apparently, to do so, I need to get to a certain number of points on the boss level (Fangora).  All the advice I have seen says "Catch the fireballs he spits at you".  I've been doing this (and have managed to achieve a gold medal for the level), but the catchable fireballs seem to happen randomly (the rest just collapse into nothingness) and I've never seen it more than once per level, so I haven't yet received enough points to achieve the "Bonus patch" level.

Is this a matter of timing?  Do I need to be closer to the dragon or something, and catch them earlier?  Or is it genuinely random, and I just have to keep catching the fireballs until they give me something to hold on to...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Tapping* the <kbd>1</kbd> button: Whip
*Holding down* the <kbd>1</kbd> button: Roll up enemy

You have to hold the <kbd>1</kbd> button for a longer period of time in order to roll up the fireball instead of just whipping at it.

Comment: This is what happens when I don't watch the tutorial level guide thingies hard enough...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I'm way too late, but I just discovered how to do it. When the dragon spits fireballs, you throw one at him, but don't pull the ball. After that, he will try to hit you with his tongue, again don't pull the ball. He will spit fireballs again :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically all you do is whenever he throws fire balls at you, pick one and throw it at him. Then just dodge the rest of his attacks. Keep at it and he will keep dropping beads.